# Adding label to secondary axis in R

Tags: r, axis-labels

I have this code:

```
# Plotting everything
plot( p1, col= "lightgreen", xlim=c(-2.5,4.5), ylim=c(0, 700), main="Daily Total Precipitation for AR and Oct-May", xlab="ln(x)" , ylab="Frequency", xaxt = "n")  # first histogram
plot( p2, col="red", xlim=c(-2.5,4.5), ylim=c(0, 700), xaxt = "n" , add=T)
# Adding in text labels on top of the bars
text(x, y, paste(round(percents,2),"%"), cex=0.50, pos=3, offset=0.3, col="black")
axis(side=1, at=breaks)     # new x-axis
# parameter that needs to be set to add a new graph on top of the other ones
par(new=T)
plot(x, percents, xlim=c(-2.5,4.5), type="l", col="yellow", lwd=3.0, axes=F, ylab=NA, xlab=NA)
axis(side=4, at=seq(0,100,by=10), col="yellow", col.axis="yellow")     # additional y-axis
mtext("Percent", side=4, col="yellow")
# legend settings
legend("topleft", c("AR", "Oct-May"), lwd=10, col=c("red", "lightgreen"))
```

Which produces this graph:

[image]

And I can't seem to figure out how to get the secondary y-axis label to show up in the correct position.  Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Edit:  Using RStudio.

Comment: You need to include some data to make this problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Define `p1`, `p2, `x`, `y`, `percents`. What is the desired output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is to specify the `line` argument to `mtext()`. In the example below I add a couple more lines to the right (`side = 4`) margin of the plot using `par()`, and then I draw three labels using `mtext()` at the default (`line = 0`), line 3 (`line = 3`), and line -3 (`line = -3`):

```
op <- par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.1)
plot(1:10)
mtext("line0", side = 4)
mtext("line3", side = 4, line = 3)
mtext("line-3", side = 4, line = -3)
par(op)
```

[image]

Note that line numbers increase *away* from the plot region and that negative `line` values move into the plot region, or to the left of the right boundary of the plot region.

It takes a little playing with the number of margin lines (as set in `par(mar = x)`) and which line you want to draw on using `mtext()`, but a little trial and error should get you what you want.

Note also that you **don't** need to specify *integer* values for the `line` argument. You can specify fractions of lines too: `line = 2.5`.